# Spyder/Anaconda Navigator will not launch after Installing Geopandas

Tags: installation, package, anaconda, spyder, geopandas

I'm trying to integrate geopandas, plotly, and shply onto my workbench to make some statistical analysis and visualization easier.  I have successfully integrated plotly after using the:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

comand in my anaconda prompt.  However, when I repeat the process for geopandas

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

my spyder client and anaconda clients no longer open.

I have tried a few clean uninstall/re-install of the latest anaconda distribution package, but have yet to find a fix.  Do I need to create separate environments to work in?  How would I go about this?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This kind of problem is usually caused by mixing packages from different channels. In your case, you're mixing packages from the `plotly`, `conda-forge` and `defaults` channels. In particular, `defaults` (the packages provided by default in Anaconda) and `conda-forge` are binary incompatible because their packages are compiled differently.

To avoid this, you need to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda because you corrupted it. Then you can simply run

`conda install plotly geopandas`

given that these two packages are part of the `defaults` channel.

Comment: Appreciate the response!